# For groups $G,\bar{G},H$; $H$ abelian; and $\phi:G\to\bar{G}$, a homomorphism, if $H≤G$ with $\ker(\phi)⊆H$, then $∀g∈G,∀h∈H,ghg^{-1}∈H$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

I have the following question:

Let $G  ,\bar{G}$ and $H$ be groups, suppose $H$ is abelian. Suppose that $\phi: G  \rightarrow \bar{G}$ is a homomorphism. If $H \leq G $ such that $\ker(\phi) \subseteq H$, then prove $\forall g \in G, \forall h \in H, ghg^{-1}\in H$.

My attempt at the above question is that the statement is false. The counter example I have is:
Take $G = \bar{G} = S_3, H = \{e, (1~2)\}$. So $H$ is abelian. $\phi: S_3 \rightarrow S_3 $ where $\phi(\alpha) = \alpha, \alpha \in S_3$. Then $\ker(\phi) = \{e\} \subseteq H \leq G$. But $(1~2~3)(1~2)(1~2~3)^{-1} = (2~3) \not\in H$.

Is my example correct? Or did I do something wrong? Because I think the statement is suppose to be true.

Comment: What does $H≤ G$ mean?  Does it mean subgroup (though you appear to use $H\subseteq G$ for that)?  Does it mean normal subgroup (in which case the desired claim is obvious). In any case, as written the claim appears to have very little to do with $\phi$.

Comment: @lulu yes $\leq$ means subgroup and $\subseteq$ is a subset

Comment: But then why do you write $\{e\}\subseteq H$?  $\{e\}$ is clearly a subgroup of $H$.

Comment: @lulu, $\leq$ is standard notation for subgroup, and $\triangleleft$ is normal subgroup

Comment: In any case, if the notation just means subgroup then the claim is obviously false.  Any non-normal subgroup $H$ provides a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

If so, then any abelian subgroup would be normal.  That would be a surprise.  And indeed counterexamples abound.  For instance, any symmetric group ($n\ge3$), has a non-normal subgroup which is abelian.

(Note:  as @lulu remarked, the homomorphism barely comes into play, since you can always take an injective one, including, say, the identity)